# payment gateway using Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, xml, soap, webservices-client

Hi 
I am getting the user credit card info and and I would like to submit to a company using webservice, what are the best practices for that?

I am using Webservices, soap and XML, how does the submiossion happens? 
thansk

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the specific payment gateway you use, there is no standard method. The payemnt gateway should provide documentation.

Comment: In addition, if you are storing the credit card information in any way your hosting provider must be pci compliant.